Python matplolib, plotting value every 2H per day
I’m having trouble with plotting a certain way in python with matplotlib.
I’m making an interface where I’m receiving data from a chip, the data is then saved in csv format, one  csv per day (name of cv are in the format YYYY-MM-DD) and the columns are Timestamp (HH-MM-SS), DO, pH, Temperature, those last three are floats.
Currently I have a tab for a 4H graph where I plot three graphs (one for each category) and another tab for showing an averaged value per day of each graphs. I’d like to change that last graph and that instead of averaging the values of one csv per day, I want to display a value every 2 hours every day, corresponding to 12 values per day/csv except I don’t really know how to do so and I’ve searched a lot and couldn’t find something similar, does anyone know how to do so? Also to precise I do not want to average those values, it has to be the value that is saved every 2 hours.
For example, here’s what I currently have:

(y axis is the DO, x axis is the date)
And what I’d like to display instead:

And here’s my code, I truncated the Class Graph4H part because it is not useful, it's more to do with the Class Graph24H:
from settings import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from settings_menu import Widget

class Graph(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master: Misc, type: Literal["4H", "24H"], title: str, ylabel: str, color: str, graphs: list[FigureCanvasTkAgg], data: dict[str, list[float]]):
        super().__init__(master=master, corner_radius=0)
        self.app = master.master.master
        self._type = type # Type de graphique 4H ou 24H
        self.title = title # Titre du graphique
        self.ylabel = ylabel # Nom de l'axe des ordonnées
        self.data = data
        self.color = color

        # Extraction de la catégorie du graphique à partir du titre pour pouvoir mettre les bonnes données dans les bons graphs
        self.category: Literal["DO", "pH", "Temperature"] = self.title.split("Graph ")[1]

        # Variables de contrôle pour le zoom des données affichées
        self.zoom_value: ctk.IntVar = self.master.master.zoom_value
        self.delta: ctk.IntVar = self.master.master.delta # For the values
        self.graphs: list[FigureCanvasTkAgg] = graphs # Liste des graphiques existants

        # self.ready = ctk.BooleanVar(value=False)

    def initialize_data(self):
        if self.data is None:
            self.app.log_error(ValueError(f"Graph {self.category} data is None")) # Affiche un message d'erreur indiquant que les données du graphique sont nulles
            return

        self.timestamps = self.data["time"]
        self.values = self.data["values"]

        # Obtention des limites de la catégorie (DO, pH, Température)
        self.category_value = get_category_boundaries(self.app, self.category)

        # Obtention des limites supérieure et inférieure (seuils) de la catégorie du graphique
        self.upper_boundary, self.lower_boundary = self.category_value

        self.create_graph()
        

    # Fonction appelée lors du zoom sur le graphique
    def on_zoom(self, event):
        x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = event.artist.xy
        self.ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
        self.ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()  # Update the canvas after zoom

    def create_graph(self):
        value_amount = 14400//self.delta.get() if self._type == "4H" else len(self.timestamps)
        x_axis = [i // (self.delta.get() / 60) for i in range(value_amount)] if self._type == "4H" else self.timestamps  # Convert to hours
        data_skip = {"DO":2, "pH":3, "Temperature":5}[self.category]

        # Création du graphique
        ax: plt.Axes
        fig: Figure
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=self.zoom_value.get()) #dpi = zoom amount
        
        if self._type == "4H":
            # Set major ticks every hour
            def hour_formatter(x, pos):
                """Custom formatter to display hours with "H" suffix"""
                hours = int(x / (self.delta.get())/3)
                return f"{hours}H"
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hour_formatter)

        ax.set_ylabel(ylabel=self.ylabel, fontsize = 25)
        ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=25)  # Set tick font size
        ax.grid(True)
        
        plt.plot(x_axis,self.values, color=self.color, linewidth=0.6) # Tracé du graphique

        # Configuration des limites et des seuils sur l'axe des ordonnées
        ax.set_yticks([i for i in range(int(self.lower_boundary)-2, int(self.upper_boundary)+3, data_skip)])
        ax.set_xlim(0, value_amount) # Set x-axis limits based on number of hours
        ax.set_ylim(self.lower_boundary-2, self.upper_boundary+2)
        ax.plot([self.lower_boundary for _ in range(value_amount)], "--", color=PURE_RED)
        ax.plot([self.upper_boundary for _ in range(value_amount)], "--", color=PURE_RED)

        # Création du widget Tkinter pour afficher le graphique
        try:
            graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self)
            graph.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        except Exception as e:
            return

        # Ajout du graphique dans la liste des graphiques existants
        self.graphs.append(graph)
        if len(self.graphs) > 3:
            plt.close(self.graphs[0].figure)
            del self.graphs[0]
            
        graph.draw()# Mise à jour de l'affichage du graphique
        # self.ready.set(True)

class GraphMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self, master, title: str, func: Callable):
        super().__init__(master=master, title=title)

        self.get_data = func # Fonction pour obtenir les données du graphique
        self.graphs: list[FigureCanvasTkAgg] = [] # Liste des graphiques existants

        # Variables de contrôle pour le zoom des données affichées
        self.delta = ctk.IntVar(value=30)
        self.zoom_value = ctk.IntVar(value=70)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self) -> None:
        self.loading_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, corner_radius=0)

        self.loading_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.loading_frame, text="Chargement des données...")
        self.loading_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

        self.graph_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, corner_radius=0)

    # Création des graphiques en fonction du type spécifié 4H ou 24H
    def create_graphs(self, _type: Literal["4H", "24H"]) -> None:
        self._type = _type
        self.graph_frame.place_forget()

        data = self.get_data()

        # Création des graphiques pour DO, pH et Température
        self.graph_do = Graph(
            master=self.graph_frame,
            type=self._type,
            title="Graph DO",
            ylabel="DO \n (mg/L)",
            color=PURE_BLUE,
            graphs=self.graphs,
            data={"time": data["time"], "values": data["values"]["DO"]}
        )
        self.graph_ph = Graph(
            master=self.graph_frame,
            type=self._type,
            title="Graph pH",
            ylabel="pH",
            color=PURE_GREEN,
            graphs=self.graphs,
            data={"time": data["time"], "values": data["values"]["pH"]}
        )
        self.graph_temp = Graph(
            master=self.graph_frame,
            type=self._type,
            title="Graph Temperature",
            ylabel="Température \n (°C)",
            color=DARK_RED,
            graphs=self.graphs,
            data={"time": data["time"], "values": data["values"]["Temperature"]}
        )

        # Placement des sous-frames dans le frame principal
        self.graph_do.place(relx=0.05, rely=0, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.3)
        self.graph_ph.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.3)
        self.graph_temp.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.3)

        self.loading_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.update()

        self.graph_do.initialize_data()
        self.graph_ph.initialize_data()
        self.graph_temp.initialize_data()

        _rely = 0.1 if _type == "4H" else 0.05
        _relheight = 0.85 if _type == "4H" else 0.9
        self.after(1000, lambda: self.graph_frame.place(relx=0, rely=_rely, relwidth=1, relheight=_relheight))
        self.update()
class Graph4H(GraphMenu):…

class Graph24H(GraphMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, title: str):
        super().__init__(master=master, title=title, func=self.get_data_for_last_24h)
        self.extra = lambda: self.create_graphs("24H")

    def get_data_for_last_24h(self) -> dict[str, dict[Literal["DO", "pH", "Temperature"], list[int]]]:
        # Fonction pour obtenir les données pour la catégorie spécifiée (DO, pH, Température) sur les 4 dernières heures
        data = {"time": [], "values": {"DO": [], "pH": [], "Temperature": []}}

        loaded_data: dict[str, dict[str, list[float]]] = self.master.load_data(get_data_filenames())
        for day, day_values in loaded_data.items():
            data["time"].append(day)
            for category in ["DO", "pH", "Temperature"]:
                data["values"][category].append(day_values[category])

        return data

I also tried to replace def get_data_for_last_24H by this one but it did not yield anything:
def get_data_for_last_24h(self) -> dict[str, dict[Literal["DO", "pH", "Temperature"], list[int]]]:
        # Function to get data for the last 24 hours with points every 2 hours
        data = {"time": [], "values": {"DO": [], "pH": [], "Temperature": []}}

        loaded_data: dict[str, dict[str, list[float]]] = self.master.load_data(get_data_filenames())
        for day, day_values in loaded_data.items():
            if "time" in day_values:
                for timestamp in day_values["time"]:
                    # Extract hour from timestamp (assuming format HH:mm:ss)
                    hour = int(timestamp.split(":")[0])
                    # Check if hour is divisible by 2 (represents data point every 2 hours)
                    if hour % 2 == 0:
                        data["time"].append(timestamp)
                        for category in ["DO", "pH", "Temperature"]:
                            data["values"][category].append(day_values[category])
            else:
                # Handle the case where there are no timestamps for this day
                print(f"Warning: No timestamps found for day {day}")


The function for sampling every second hour is .asfreq('2h'). It just selects the row; it does not average.

Most of the date formatting is done by matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter() which has good defaults. In order to match your format more closely, it took a few more lines where we tell the formatter to render hours as "6H" rather than its default "06:00".
Reproducible example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Data for testing
dates = pd.date_range('1 May 2024', '4 May 2024', freq='h')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'DO': np.random.uniform(5, 16, dates.size),
        'pH': np.random.uniform(7, 7.5, size=dates.size),
        'Temperature': np.random.uniform(28, 34, size=dates.size)
    },
    index=dates
)
df

#
# Resample down to a 2H frequency - this will keep every 2h data point
#
df_resampled = df.asfreq('2h')
df_resampled

#
# Plot
#
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

#Plot the data and guide lines
plot_col = 'DO'

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 2.5), layout='tight')
ax.plot(
    df_resampled.index, df_resampled[plot_col],
    marker='s', markersize=5, linewidth=1.5, color='dodgerblue', label=plot_col
)
[ax.axhline(y, color='tab:red', linestyle=':', linewidth=1) for y in [7, 13]]

#Set the plot date range
ax.set_xlim(mdates.datestr2num(['1 May 2024', '3 May 2024']))

#Add grids and labels
ax.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5)
ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel=plot_col)

#Configure the x axis ticks and formats
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=2))

#Default would format the time as "06:00". OP requires "6H".
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(
    locator=ax.xaxis.get_major_locator(),
    formats=['%Y', '%b', '%d', '%-HH', '%-HH', '%S.%f'],  #changed the time to %-HH
    zero_formats=['', '%Y', '%b', '%b-%d', '%H:%M', '%H:%M'] #added ""-%d" to %b
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

#Final formatting
ax.spines[['right', 'top']].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=25)

